# CSS Child Selector (>) not working with certain properties

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I tried to apply certain CSS properties to direct child of a parent element using ">", it works well with some of the properties like border, but not with font-properties like color, font-weight etc..

My HTML is

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Subitem 2A</li>
      <li>Subitem 2B</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CASE1** CSS:

```
ul>li {
    color:#F00;
}
```

With the above CSS code, the `color: #F00` property gets applied to all the `li` elements comes under the parent and its child. The expected was, it should be applied only to the direct child `li`s.

**CASE 2**
CSS:

```
ul>li {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

The above code works as expected and the border gets applied only to the direct `li` child.

**I know this can be fixed by overriding it with another class. But wanted to know the reason why some of those CSS properties are inherited to all levels of hierarchy and others not**.

Comment: What do you mean from direct "li"s ?

Comment: The `li` children of `ol` are inheriting the color from the ancestor `li`s

Comment: Do yourself a favor and add some classes!

Comment: As it has been noted, the color value is inherited to the inner `li`s so you have to manually override it with another rule below

Comment: @koala_dev, thanks, i know that its due to the inheritance, but why only certain properties gets inherited and others not

Comment: Check the [full list of CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html) in W3, it's specified there which are inherited by default

Comment: @Musa, thanks, but why only certain properties like color and font-weight gets inherited and others not. (could you please look into my edited question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's happening due to the default inheritance capability of certain CSS Properties. Values of these kind of properties will be transmitted to the child by default.**

This document from W3C gives detailed list of inheritance in various CSS properties. [Full property table](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html)

Comment: @BoltClock Those answers were talking about how to override the condition, that i have already know. But the thing i looked for is the reason behind this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CMVUG/)

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>Subitem 2A</li>
      <li>Subitem 2B</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul > li {
    color:#F00;
}
ul > li > ol > li {
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ul > li ol li {color:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the listing element has been inheriting the color property from its parent, you need to override it.

You can add below style before yours as like

```
li { 
    color: #000; 
}

ul>li { 
    color:#F00;
}
```

It overrides the color: inherit value.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might find the answer you need here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

You should be able to select these elements with

```
ul:first-child {

// css

}
```

Hope this helps